# Python: Append array columns in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem.

I have several parameters, all integers or floats, and I want to stack them in a for loop. I tried different thinks like:

```
for i in range(0,19000):
    parameterCombinationsResults = np.array([]).reshape(0,12)
    parameterCombinationsResults = np.r_[parameterCombinationsResults,[[self.cR,self.fD,s[0]+1,s[1]+1,self.cI,self.cO,self.fI,self.fO,maxJC,maxSensitivity,maxSpecifity,numberOfCells]]]
```

The problem is, that in every loop iteration the old values are stacked as well of course, so I have in every loop the old results+the new results which will result in an array with thousands of copies of the old results. Is there a way like list append. I know arrays are immutable but maybe there is a workaround?

In the end I want to save all this parametercombination results in a csv. It dont have to be arrays I would also be itnerested in a list approach, the important thing is to save them in a csv and that it has to be very fast.

Comment: in which way is this post related to ``scipy``?

Comment: you are right, sorry I used a wrong tag

Comment: Please give us a [mcve]

Comment: In general it is better to collect values in a loop using list append, and do the array construction, once, at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a numpy method called vstack.  Here's an example from the numpy website

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
np.vstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Applying this to your code would make it look like

```
pcr_stack = parameterCombinationsResults  #need to start one for vstack to work

for i in range(0,19000):
    pcr_stack = vstack([pcr_stack,[self.cR,self.fD,s[0]+1,s[1]+1,self.cI,self.cO,self.fI,self.fO,maxJC,maxSensitivity,maxSpecifity,numberOfCells]])
```